# Failed to install fbprophet in Google compute engine VM

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to install fbprophet in GCE VM which I create using API call and a startup_script, here is the link I followed to [create GCE instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance)

I am using pip to install 'fbprophet' and 'google-cloud-storage' is also not getting installed in the instance.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pEW_t1/matplotlib
```

startup_script.sh

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential python-tk 
apt-get install -y libev4 libev-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev

easy_install pip

sudo pip install google-cloud-storage
sudo pip install pandas
sudo pip install pandas-gbq
sudo pip install datetime
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install matplotlib
sudo pip install Cython
sudo pip install pystan
sudo pip install fbprophet
```

is there anything I missed? 
Why is the google-cloud-storage not getting installed?

Comment: Have you tried the solution? The point is you should wait until all the processes finish, and they take some time.

Comment: It's working when I change the machine type image to Ubuntu instead of Debian. This is not the solution but just a workaround only.

Comment: I can tell you that if you wait enough, it works on Debian too.

Comment: ok. I got your point. But in my case, the process which I need to execute using the VM should start immediately once its initiate the call.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing tests with the official Debian 9 image and all I see is that the script takes a long time, especially when compiling [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/). So you won't see the changes right after creating the VM. I tried this one and it worked:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential python-tk libev4 libev-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev

sudo pip install google-cloud-storage
sudo pip install pandas
sudo pip install pandas-gbq
sudo pip install datetime
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install matplotlib
sudo pip install Cython
sudo pip install pystan
sudo pip install fbprophet==0.2.0
```

Hope this helps.